# opencv nodejs _handle error while requiring it in js page

Tags: node.js, opencv

I have installed the opencv using npm, but when I require it in my js page like this:

```
var cv = require('opencv');
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property '_handle' of undefined
```

[image]

Comment: Which opencv did you install node-opencv or opencv.js?

Comment: its node opencv

Comment: The thing is, you cant use node opencv in the browser, for this purpose you need opencv.js

Comment: So , how can i get opencv.js